# dynamoDB: missed schema element

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I've been trying to query my DynamoDB table, that has daily_answers partition key and timestamp sort key. Yet, this query gives an error of **"Query condition missed key schema element: daily_answers"**

What am I doing wrong here? Answers much appreciated.

````
const sevenDaysAgo = new Date(now.getTime() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
const sevenDaysAgoTs = Math.floor(sevenDaysAgo.getTime() / 1000);
let dbQueryResult;

// Query the last 7 days of answers
const queryParams = {
  TableName: tableName,
  KeyConditionExpression: 'partition_key = :pk AND #ts >= :seven_days_ago',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#ts': 'timestamp',
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':pk': 'daily_answers',
    ':seven_days_ago': sevenDaysAgoTs,
  },
  ScanIndexForward: false,
};

async function fetchAnswers() {
    try {
      const data = await dynamodb.query(queryParams).promise();
      dbQueryResult = data.Items.map((item) => item.answers);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error querying DynamoDB:', JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    }
  }

  await fetchAnswers();```
````

Answer (score 1):

When you make a DynamoDB query, you need to provide the value of the partition key (not just its name).  The kind of an SQL-style query you apparently have in mind unfortunately does not work on NoSQL databases.  Unless you have a clever attribute that partitions your table by time periods (which would allow you to create a GSI for it, and then query this GSI), you are stuck with having to run an expensive `scan` operation on the entire table and then filtering the results.

Answer (score 1):

Try these parameters:

```
const sevenDaysAgo = new Date(now.getTime() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
const sevenDaysAgoTs = Math.floor(sevenDaysAgo.getTime() / 1000);
let dbQueryResult;

const dailyValue = 'some value'

const queryParams = {
  TableName: tableName,
  KeyConditionExpression: '#pk = :pk AND #ts >= :seven_days_ago',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#ts': 'timestamp',
    '#pk': 'daily_answers'
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':pk': dailyValue,
    ':seven_days_ago': sevenDaysAgoTs,
  },
  ScanIndexForward: false,
};
```

You need to provide the value for you Partition key. Whatever it is you used to save the value of the item.